# Is there a keyboard shortcut to close dialog (OK), whilst in text box?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

For example (pictured) if I'm using uTorrent; in the Properties dialog of a torrent, I've pasted my information into the text box, now I want to close the dialog via the "OK" button so it saves changes, using the keyboard, with a minimum number of keystrokes (ideally, one). The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will just put a new line in the text box. I remember I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for something similar on a specific program I think, can't remember which, but it was like a forced <kbd>Enter</kbd> you could use at any time.

[image: uTorrent Screenshot]

At the moment for this particular situation in uTorrent I am using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go one step back in the tab order to the "OK" button and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I would like to know if a shorter shortcut – ideally one that doesn't depend on the relative locations of the text box and the "OK" button – exists.

Comment: What about just "Tab + Enter"? One less key stroke than "Shift + Tab + Enter" at least

Comment: That will go forward in the tab order. I'd have to press Tab 9 times to get to the OK button.

Comment: Did you try it? I don't have uTorrent but my intuition would leave me to believe that it would only require 1 tab since the next input box is not multiline.

Comment: Ahh. I see what you mean. Yes that does work, thanks. I guess in this example that is quick enough to satisfy, I'd be interested to know though if a specific shortcut existed, in case next time the tab order is not so friendly..

Comment: "Ctrl + Enter" works for at least one program that I use, but if that doesn't work my only other guess would be "Shift + Enter". I'm not aware of any universal shortcut

Answer (score 1):

I don't use uTorrent anymore, but most dialog boxes still make the [OK] button the default action for the 'O' hotkey, which means you can trigger it from anywhere while the window is open by hitting [Alt+O] (that's o as in Oscar, not zero). Tapping [Alt] should show the hotkey underlines (*side note: why doesn't StackExchange allow underlines?*), though you'll still have to hold [Alt] while using the hotkey.

Otherwise, [Tab] until you're not in a multi-line box then hitting [Enter] works. The [OK] button is set as the "default" (meaning [Enter] triggers it; if there's a [Cancel] button you can trigger it with [Esc]) in nearly all such settings windows and is very easy to specify in Visual Studio, though it's technically still just a convention that a developer can choose to ignore.

Comment: _Because underlined text on the web insinuates it is a link._

Comment: Nothing on any SE site seems to use underlines for links, it uses a distinct blue color. Underlined black doesn't look much like a link anyhow, especially if it doesn't change color on hover. Besides, the very minor annoyance of not being able to click something you thought was clickable seems like a really silly reason to restrict styling at all, much less to disallow something that looks clickable only on sites with very different styling than this one.